# Microsoft report builder loop/cycle over a field

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

Lets say I created a report for clients. Is it possible to generate/create the report for all clients in a certain list? In other words, can i create a report that will loop/cycle over/through a list and create the report for each x in that list?

Don't know a way to describe it better i'm afraid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, this is exactly what sub reports will do.

So assuming you have a report that shows data for a single client and also assuming that this report takes one or more parameters (e.g. ClientID) then all you need to do it the following...

Create a new report.
Add a dataset that contains a list of `ClientID`s that you want to produce a report for. You can optionally parameterise this dataset query just like any other dataset.

Now add a table to your report then set the dataset property of the table to point to your dataset containing your `ClientID`s.

In the table, on the detail row, right-click the first cell and choose 'insert => subreport'. The 'cell' will be filled with a subreport placeholder. Right-Click this and go to subreport properties. Choose you original report as the subreport. On hte parameters tab, add an entry. Set the parameter name of the target report's parameter (this should appear if you click the drop down). In the value field set this to be the CLientID from your dataset (again the drop down should provide a list of available fields).

You can remove any unused cells in the table if you like.

When you run the report, the subreport will be executed for each entry in your dataset.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Will try this tomorrow. Is this the only way to achieve this?

Comment: It's not the only way but as you have your report already it's the easiest. I do these all the time and this would be 10 or 15minutes work, it sounds harder than it is.

Comment: I'm currently trying out a few options on reporting and im just exploring report builders options, could you tell me what the other options are? Or give me a link where I can look it up? I have no idea what to google for when looking myself.

Comment: You can use a group to wrap the current structure in and then page breaks on that but I find that method harder to mange in the long term.

Comment: Tried this and running into some errors. Im starting to wonder, will this method create seperate reports? Or will it create the table with the ClientID's i selected and for each ClientID a report in the table? 

Because I acutally need seperate reports for each client.

Comment: This will create a single report with each client on a new page. if you want to create a new report for each you would have to write something outside SSRS to call each report. You can do this with report subscriptions (I can't help on this more than that) but data driven subscriptions are only available with SQL Server Enterprise edition as far as I know.